# Memory of two variables are colliding when used malloc

Tags: c, malloc, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm trying to learn the memory allocation in C using malloc and increasing the size of allocated array using realloc inside a function. I came across this. when I use single variable the code is working well. But when I allocate memory for second variable, it gives me weird output.

Code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

# define N 3

void padd(int *a){
    int sizes = 10*sizeof(int);
    a = (void *)realloc(a,sizes);
    a[0] = 10;
    printf("inside func= %d \n",a[0]);
}

int main()
{
    int *d;
    int *pA;
    
    int size = N*sizeof(int);
    pA = (void *)malloc(size);
    //d = (int *)malloc(size);
    
    padd(pA);
    printf("outside func= %d",pA[0]);
    
}
```

it gives me output:

```
inside func= 10
outside func= 10
```

but if I uncomment the //d = (int *)malloc(size); line, It gives me

```
inside func= 10 
outside func= -1368048824
```

as output.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: `a` is changed only locally. The result of `realloc()` is lost after the function returns.

Comment: Ok! is there a correct way to increase the size of the pA inside the function? I'm new to C.:)

Comment: Use a pointer to the pointer and assign that one, or return the pointer obtained with `realloc()` and assign it back to the original.

Comment: `realloc(a, sizes)` may return the original `a` when increasing the allocated size, but it is not required to.  It also can return `NULL` on failure.   Your code will only behave as you expect if `realloc()` succeeds (does not return `NULL`) AND returns the original `a`

Comment: As a general rule, you should not cast the result of `malloc` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `realloc` can’t extend a buffer in place, it will allocate a new buffer, copy the contents of the old buffer to it, free the old buffer, and return the address of the new buffer (or `NULL` if it cannot satisfy the request); thus, the value of `a` can change in `padd`.  However, that change is only applied to the formal parameter `a` - the actual parameter `pA` is not affected.

Based on the behavior, it *looks* like that if you allocate `d`, it’s allocated immediately after `pA` such that `pA` can’t be extended in place, so `realloc` is creating a new buffer and deallocating the old one, and the old buffer is overwritten before the `printf` statement in `main`.

You’ll want to write `padd` such that any changes to `a` are reflected in `pA` - either return the (potentially new) value of `a` or pass a pointer to `pA`:

```
void padd( int **a )
{
  size_t sizes = 10 * sizeof (int); // see note 1
  int *tmp = realloc( *a, sizes ); // see note 2
  
  if ( tmp )
  {
    *a = tmp;
    (*a)[0] = 10;
    printf( "Inside func, (*a)[0] = %d\n", (*a)[0] );
  }
  else
  {
    printf ( "Inside func, realloc failed!\n" );
  }
}
```

and you’d call it as

```
padd( &pA );
```

Note 1: `sizeof` has type `size_t`, not `int`.

Note 2: Since `realloc` can potentially return `NULL`, *always* assign the result to a temporary value and check it before assigning back to the original variable, otherwise you run the risk of losing access to memory you’ve already allocated.  Also, the cast to `void *` is unnecessary and confusing since you’re assigning the result to an `int *` variable.  Unless you’re compiling this code as C++ or under an *ancient* K&R C compiler, just leave the cast off completely - otherwise, your cast has to match the type of the thing you’re assigning to, which in this case is `int *`.

Answer (score 2):

You should either get the new pointer back from `padd`:

```
int * padd(int * a){
    int sizes = 10*sizeof(int);
    a = (void *)realloc(a,sizes);
    a[0] = 10;
    printf("inside func= %d \n",a[0]);
    return a;
}
//...
int main()
{
    //...
    pA = padd(pA);
    //...
}
```

Or pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void padd(int **pA){
    int *a = *pA;
    int sizes = 10*sizeof(int);
    a = (void *)realloc(a,sizes);
    a[0] = 10;
    printf("inside func= %d \n",a[0]);
    *pA = a;
}
//...
int main()
{
    //...
    padd(&pA);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The both your programs have undefined behavior.

The function parameter `a`

```
void padd(int *a)
```

is a local variable of the function that is initialized by the value of the pointer `pA` used as a function argument in the function call

```
padd(pA);
```

You can imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
padd(pA);

//...

void padd( /* int *a */ ){
    int *a = pA;

    int sizes = 10*sizeof(int);
    a = (void *)realloc(a,sizes);
    a[0] = 10;
    printf("inside func= %d \n",a[0]);
}
```

So as it is seen changing the local variable `a`  within the function `padd` does not influence on the value stored in the pointer `pA` because the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `pA`.

To change the original pointer `pA` within the function you need to pass it to the function by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer you will get a direct access to the object.

The function should be declared and defined the following way

```
int padd( int **a ){
    int sizes = 10*sizeof(int);

    int *tmp = realloc( *a, size );
    int success = tmp != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        *a = tmp;
        ( *a )[0] = 10;
        // or **a = 10;
        printf("inside func= %d \n", ( *a )[0] );
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
if ( padd( &pA () ) printf("outside func= %d",pA[0]);
```

Pay attention to that to call `realloc` you should use an intermediate variable because in general the function can return a null pointer. So reassigning the original pointer with a null pointer results in the original value of the pointer will be lost.

Also you should free all the dynamically allocated memory when it is not needed any more

```
free( pA );
```